# create cloudformation template which create a Dev &Prod env with Multi AZ/ ELB, Wordpress installed with 1 RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, aws-cloudformation

hi i am currently working on a cloudformation template which creates one RDS instance, one EC2 instance in HA and Multi AZ and wordpress installed on it.
however i want to create another ec2 instance with wordpress installed on it with using same RDS which i used previously. so that it can be 2 environment named dev and prod.
i wrote this much template,

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: "Wordpress: highly available and scalable"
Parameters:
BlogID:
Description: "A unique identifier for your blog. For internal use only."
Type: String
AllowedPattern: "[A-Za-z0-9\\-]+"
ConstraintDescription: "Only letters, digits or dash allowed."
BlogTitle:
Description: "The title of the Wordpress blog."
Type: String
Default: "Just another Wordpress blog"
BlogAdminUsername:
Description: "A username for the Wordpress admin."
Type: String
Default: "admin"
BlogAdminPassword:
Description: "A password for the Wordpress admin."
Type: String
NoEcho: "true"
BlogAdminEMail:
Description: "The email address of the Wordpress admin."
Type: String
WebServerKeyName:
Description: "The key pair to establish a SSH connection to the web     servers."
Type: "AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName"
WebServerInstanceType:
Description: "The instance type of web servers (e.g. t2.micro)."
Type: String
Default: "t2.micro"
DBServerInstanceType:
Description: "The instance type of database server (e.g. db.t2.micro)."
Type: String
Default: "db.t2.micro"

Mappings:
EC2RegionMap:
ap-northeast-1: { AmazonLinuxAMIHVMEBSBacked64bit: "ami-cbf90ecb" }
ap-southeast-1: { AmazonLinuxAMIHVMEBSBacked64bit: "ami-68d8e93a" }
ap-southeast-2: { AmazonLinuxAMIHVMEBSBacked64bit: "ami-fd9cecc7" }
eu-central-1: { AmazonLinuxAMIHVMEBSBacked64bit: "ami-a8221fb5" }
eu-west-1: { AmazonLinuxAMIHVMEBSBacked64bit: "ami-a10897d6" }
sa-east-1: { AmazonLinuxAMIHVMEBSBacked64bit: "ami-b52890a8" }
us-east-1: { AmazonLinuxAMIHVMEBSBacked64bit: "ami-1ecae776" }
us-west-1: { AmazonLinuxAMIHVMEBSBacked64bit: "ami-d114f295" }
us-west-2: { AmazonLinuxAMIHVMEBSBacked64bit: "ami-e7527ed7" }

Resources:
VPC:
Type: "AWS::EC2::VPC"
Properties:
  CidrBlock: "172.31.0.0/16"
  EnableDnsHostnames: "true"

InternetGateway:
Type: "AWS::EC2::InternetGateway"
Properties: {}

VPCGatewayAttachment:
Type: "AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment"
Properties:
  VpcId: {"Ref": "VPC"}
  InternetGatewayId: {"Ref": "InternetGateway"}

SubnetA:
Type: "AWS::EC2::Subnet"
Properties:
  AvailabilityZone: {"Fn::Select": ["0", {"Fn::GetAZs": ""}]}
  CidrBlock: "172.31.38.0/24"
  VpcId: {"Ref": "VPC"}

SubnetB:
Type: "AWS::EC2::Subnet"
Properties:
  AvailabilityZone: {"Fn::Select": ["1", {"Fn::GetAZs": ""}]}
  CidrBlock: "172.31.37.0/24"
  VpcId: {"Ref": "VPC"}

RouteTable:
Type: "AWS::EC2::RouteTable"
Properties:
  VpcId: {"Ref": "VPC"}

RouteTableAssociationA:
Type: "AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation"
Properties:
  SubnetId: {"Ref": "SubnetA"}
  RouteTableId: {"Ref": "RouteTable"}

RouteTableAssociationB:
Type: "AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation"
Properties:
  SubnetId: {"Ref": "SubnetB"}
  RouteTableId: {"Ref": "RouteTable"}

RoutePublicNATToInternet:
Type: "AWS::EC2::Route"
Properties:
  RouteTableId: {"Ref": "RouteTable"}
  DestinationCidrBlock: "0.0.0.0/0"
  GatewayId: {"Ref": "InternetGateway"}
DependsOn: "VPCGatewayAttachment"

NetworkAcl:
Type: "AWS::EC2::NetworkAcl"
Properties:
  VpcId: {"Ref": "VPC"}

SubnetNetworkAclAssociationA:
Type: "AWS::EC2::SubnetNetworkAclAssociation"
Properties:
  SubnetId: {"Ref": "SubnetA"}
  NetworkAclId: {"Ref": "NetworkAcl"}

SubnetNetworkAclAssociationB:
Type: "AWS::EC2::SubnetNetworkAclAssociation"
Properties:
  SubnetId: {"Ref": "SubnetB"}
  NetworkAclId: {"Ref": "NetworkAcl"}

NetworkAclEntryIngress:
Type: "AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry"
Properties:
  NetworkAclId: {"Ref": "NetworkAcl"}
  RuleNumber: "100"
  Protocol: "-1"
  RuleAction: "allow"
  Egress: "false"
  CidrBlock: "0.0.0.0/0"

NetworkAclEntryEgress:
Type: "AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry"
Properties:
  NetworkAclId: {"Ref": "NetworkAcl"}
  RuleNumber: "100"
  Protocol: "-1"
  RuleAction: "allow"
  Egress: "true"
  CidrBlock: "0.0.0.0/0"

LoadBalancer:
Type: "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer"
Properties:
  Subnets: [{"Ref": "SubnetA"}, {"Ref": "SubnetB"}]
  LoadBalancerName: {"Ref": "BlogID"}
  Listeners:
    - InstancePort: "80"
      InstanceProtocol: "HTTP"
      LoadBalancerPort: "80"
      Protocol: "HTTP"
  HealthCheck:
    HealthyThreshold: "2"
    Interval: "5"
    Target: "TCP:80"
    Timeout: "3"
    UnhealthyThreshold: "2"
  SecurityGroups: [{"Ref": "LoadBalancerSecurityGroup"}]
  Scheme: "internet-facing"
  CrossZone: "true"

 LoadBalancerSecurityGroup:
 Type: "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup"
 Properties:
  GroupDescription: "wordpress-elb"
  VpcId: {"Ref": "VPC"}
  SecurityGroupIngress:
    - CidrIp: "0.0.0.0/0"
      FromPort: 80
      IpProtocol: "tcp"
      ToPort: 80

WebServerSecurityGroup:
Type: "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup"
Properties:
  GroupDescription: "wordpress-ec2"
  VpcId: {"Ref": "VPC"}
  SecurityGroupIngress:
    - CidrIp: "0.0.0.0/0"
      FromPort: 22
      IpProtocol: "tcp"
      ToPort: 22

    - FromPort: 80
      IpProtocol: "tcp"
      SourceSecurityGroupId: {"Ref": "LoadBalancerSecurityGroup"}
      ToPort: 80

DatabaseSecurityGroup:
Type: "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup"
Properties:
  GroupDescription: "wordpress-rds"
  VpcId: {"Ref": "VPC"}
  SecurityGroupIngress:
    - IpProtocol: "tcp"
      FromPort: "3306"
      ToPort: "3306"
      SourceSecurityGroupId: {"Ref": "WebServerSecurityGroup"}

Database:
Type: "AWS::RDS::DBInstance"
Properties:
  AllocatedStorage: "5"
  BackupRetentionPeriod: "0"
  DBInstanceClass: {"Ref": "DBServerInstanceType"}
  DBInstanceIdentifier: {"Ref": "BlogID"}
  DBName: "wordpress"
  Engine: "MySQL"
  MasterUsername: "wordpress"
  MasterUserPassword: "wordpress"
  VPCSecurityGroups: [{"Fn::GetAtt": ["DatabaseSecurityGroup", "GroupId"]}]
  DBSubnetGroupName: {"Ref": "DBSubnetGroup"}
  MultiAZ: "true"
  StorageType: "gp2"

DBSubnetGroup:
Type: "AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup"
Properties:
  DBSubnetGroupDescription: "DB subnet group"
  SubnetIds: [{"Ref": "SubnetA"}, {"Ref": "SubnetB"}]



IAMUser:
Type: "AWS::IAM::User"
Properties:
  Path: "/"
  Policies:
    - PolicyName: "UploadToS3"
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: "Allow"
            Action: ["s3:*"]
            Resource:
              - {"Fn::Join": ["", ["arn:aws:s3:::", {"Ref": "BlogID"} ,"/*"]]}

IAMAccessKey:
Type: "AWS::IAM::AccessKey"
Properties:
  UserName: {"Ref": "IAMUser"}

LaunchConfiguration:
Type: "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration"
Metadata:
  "AWS::CloudFormation::Init":
    config:
      packages:
        yum:
          "php": []
          "php-mysql": []
          "mysql": []
          "httpd": []
      sources: {"/var/www/html": "https://wordpress.org/wordpress-4.2.4.tar.gz"}
      files:
        "/root/config.sh":
          content:
            "Fn::Join":
              - ""
              - [
                  "#!/bin/bash -ex\n",
                  "cp wp-config-sample.php wp-config.php\n",
                  "sed -i \"s/'database_name_here'/'devwordpress'/g\" wp-config.php\n",
                  "sed -i \"s/'username_here'/'development'/g\" wp-config.php\n",
                  "sed -i \"s/'password_here'/'devolopment'/g\" wp-config.php\n",
                  "sed -i \"s/'localhost'/'", {"Fn::GetAtt": ["Database", "Endpoint.Address"]}, "'/g\" wp-config.php\n",
                  "echo \"define('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', '", {"Ref": "IAMAccessKey"},"'); \" >> wp-config.php \n",
                  "echo \"define('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY', '", {"Fn::GetAtt": ["IAMAccessKey", "SecretAccessKey"]},"'); \" >> wp-config.php \n",
                  "echo \"define( 'DISALLOW_FILE_MODS', true ); \" >> wp-config.php \n",
                  "echo \"define( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', false ); \" >> wp-config.php \n",
                  "chmod -R 777 wp-content/ \n",
                  "curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wp-cli/builds/gh-pages/phar/wp-cli.phar \n",
                  "php wp-cli.phar core install --url=\"", {"Fn::GetAtt": ["LoadBalancer", "DNSName"]}, "\" --title=\"", {"Ref": "BlogTitle"}, "\" --admin_user=\"", {"Ref": "BlogAdminUsername"}, "\" --admin_password=\"", {"Ref": "BlogAdminPassword"}, "\" --admin_email=\"", {"Ref": "BlogAdminEMail"}, "\" \n",
                  "php wp-cli.phar plugin install --activate amazon-web-services \n",
                  "php wp-cli.phar plugin install --activate amazon-s3-and-cloudfront \n",
                  "CHARCOUNT=`printf \"",{"Ref": "BlogID"} ,"\" | wc -c` \n",
                  "php wp-cli.phar db query \"DELETE FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'tantan_wordpress_s3'; INSERT INTO wp_options (option_name, option_value, autoload) VALUES('tantan_wordpress_s3', 'a:15:{s:17:\\\"post_meta_version\\\";i:1;s:6:\\\"bucket\\\";s:", "$CHARCOUNT", ":\\\"", {"Ref": "BlogID"},"\\\";s:6:\\\"region\\\";s:0:\\\"\\\";s:6:\\\"domain\\\";s:9:\\\"subdomain\\\";s:7:\\\"expires\\\";s:1:\\\"0\\\";s:10:\\\"cloudfront\\\";s:0:\\\"\\\";s:13:\\\"object-prefix\\\";s:19:\\\"wp-content/uploads/\\\";s:10:\\\"copy-to-s3\\\";s:1:\\\"1\\\";s:13:\\\"serve-from-s3\\\";s:1:\\\"1\\\";s:17:\\\"remove-local-file\\\";s:1:\\\"0\\\";s:3:\\\"ssl\\\";s:7:\\\"request\\\";s:12:\\\"hidpi-images\\\";s:1:\\\"0\\\";s:17:\\\"object-versioning\\\";s:1:\\\"0\\\";s:21:\\\"use-yearmonth-folders\\\";s:1:\\\"1\\\";s:20:\\\"enable-object-prefix\\\";s:1:\\\"1\\\";}', 'yes');\" \n"
                ]
          mode: "000500"
          owner: "root"
          group: "root"

      commands:
        01_mv:
          command: "mv * ../"
          cwd: "/var/www/html/wordpress"
        02_config:
          command: "/root/config.sh"
          cwd: "/var/www/html"

      services:
        sysvinit:
          httpd:
            enabled: "true"
            ensureRunning: "true"

  Properties:
  ImageId: {"Fn::FindInMap": ["EC2RegionMap", {"Ref": "AWS::Region"}, "AmazonLinuxAMIHVMEBSBacked64bit"]}
  InstanceType: {"Ref": "WebServerInstanceType"}
  SecurityGroups: [{"Ref": "WebServerSecurityGroup"}]
  KeyName: {"Ref": "WebServerKeyName"}
  AssociatePublicIpAddress: "true"
  UserData:
    "Fn::Base64":
      "Fn::Join":
        - ""
        - [
            "#!/bin/bash -ex\n",
            "yum update -y aws-cfn-bootstrap\n",
            "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --stack ", {"Ref": "AWS::StackName"}, " --resource LaunchConfiguration --region ", {"Ref": "AWS::Region"}, "\n",
            "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? --stack ", {"Ref": "AWS::StackName"}, " --resource AutoScalingGroup --region ", {"Ref": "AWS::Region"}, "\n"
          ]
  InstanceMonitoring: "true"

AutoScalingGroup:
Type: "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup"
Properties:
  LoadBalancerNames: [{"Ref": "LoadBalancer"}]
  LaunchConfigurationName: {"Ref": "LaunchConfiguration"}
  MinSize: "1"
  MaxSize: "2"
  DesiredCapacity: "1"
  Cooldown: "300"
  HealthCheckGracePeriod: "300"
  HealthCheckType: "ELB"
  VPCZoneIdentifier: [{"Ref": "SubnetA"}, {"Ref": "SubnetB"}]
  Tags:
    - PropagateAtLaunch: "true"
      Value: "wordpress"
      Key: "Name"


ScalingUpPolicy:
Type: "AWS::AutoScaling::ScalingPolicy"
Properties:
  AdjustmentType: "ChangeInCapacity"
  PolicyType: "SimpleScaling"
  AutoScalingGroupName: {"Ref": "AutoScalingGroup"}
  Cooldown: "300"
  ScalingAdjustment: "1"


CPUHighAlarm:
Type: "AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm"
Properties:
  EvaluationPeriods: "1"
  Statistic: "Average"
  Threshold: "99"
  AlarmDescription: "Alarm if CPU load is high."
  Period: "300"
  AlarmActions: [{"Ref": "ScalingUpPolicy"}]
  Namespace: "AWS/EC2"
  Dimensions:
    - Name: "AutoScalingGroupName"
      Value: {"Ref": "AutoScalingGroup"}
  ComparisonOperator: "GreaterThanThreshold"
  MetricName: "CPUUtilization"

ScalingDownPolicy:
Type: "AWS::AutoScaling::ScalingPolicy"
Properties:
  AdjustmentType: "ChangeInCapacity"
  PolicyType: "SimpleScaling"
  AutoScalingGroupName: {"Ref": "AutoScalingGroup"}
  Cooldown: "300"
  ScalingAdjustment: "-1"

CPULowAlarm:
Type: "AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm"
Properties:
  EvaluationPeriods: "1"
  Statistic: "Average"
  Threshold: "10"
  AlarmDescription: "Alarm if CPU load is low."
  Period: "300"
  AlarmActions: [{"Ref": "ScalingDownPolicy"}]
  Namespace: "AWS/EC2"
  Dimensions:
    - Name: "AutoScalingGroupName"
      Value: {"Ref": "AutoScalingGroup"}
  ComparisonOperator: "LessThanThreshold"
  MetricName: "CPUUtilization"


Outputs:
 URL:
 Value: {"Fn::Join": ["", ["http://", {"Fn::GetAtt": ["LoadBalancer", "DNSName"]}]]}
Description: "URL to Wordpress"
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI There are sample Cloudformation template [solutions available](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/sample-templates-applications-ap-southeast-2.html) and in particular there's one for [Wordpress](https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-ap-southeast-2/WordPress_Single_Instance.template).

I would recommended that you separate your Cloudformation template so that the RDS instance is provisioned separately to your compute resources. You would not want to accidentally delete your RDS instance when you modify your compute resources. You would also need to do this to reuse the RDS between multiple compute resources like you've described.

You can reference [outputs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/outputs-section-structure.html) from the RDS template to be used in the app tier.

Comment: Yes i tried those only at first but it did not work for me as expected.it gave me error saying 'received 0 signal while waiting for 1' something like that. so i started writing my own.
would you please provide me one sample? if you can that would be great help. thankyou